# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' - Slugify

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with my model in the line of slugify

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Pages(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    content =  models.TextField(blank=True)
    publish_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    order =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
    type_content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    status =models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title   


    def save(self,  *args, **kwargs):

        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        #self.user=self.request.user
        super(Pages, self).save( *args, **kwargs)
```

I tried putting the code self.slug = slugify("test of slug") and still the problem , but when he says keeps the information without problems

this is my Error:

> > Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL:
>   http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8000/admin/pages/pages/add/
>
> Django Version: 1.7.1 Python Version: 3.4.2 Installed Applications:
>   ('django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'seo', 
>   'pages',  'site_options',  'news',  'tags',  'category') Installed
>   Middleware: ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
>
> Traceback: File
>   "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   get_response
>     111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py"
>   in wrapper
>     584.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in
>   _wrapped_view
>     105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py"
>   in _wrapped_view_func
>     52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py"
>   in inner
>     204.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py"
>   in add_view
>     1454.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context) File
>   "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in
>   _wrapper
>     29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in
>   _wrapped_view
>     105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in
>   bound_func
>     25.                 return func.**get**(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py" in
>   inner
>     394.                 return func(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py"
>   in changeform_view
>     1405.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add) File "C:\cms-rock\cms\pages\admin.py" in save_model
>     45.         obj.save() File "C:\cms-rock\cms\pages\models.py" in save
>     37.         super(Pages, self).save( *args, **kwargs) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in
>   save
>     591.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields) File
>   "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in
>   save_base
>     619.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields) File
>   "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in
>   _save_table
>     700.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw) File
>   "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in
>   _do_insert
>     733.                                using=using, raw=raw) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in
>   manager_method
>     92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in
>   _insert
>     921.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id) File
>   "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py"
>   in execute_sql
>     920.                 cursor.execute(sql, params) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in
>   execute
>     85.             sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params) File
>   "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\base.py"
>   in last_executed_query
>     371.         return cursor.statement File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\base.py"
>   in **getattr**
>     147.         return getattr(self.cursor, attr) File "C:\cms-rock\vrockw\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py" in
>   statement
>     858.             return self._executed.strip()
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/pages/pages/add/ Exception
>   Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: This means `self.title` is `None` (of type `NoneType`). Are you sure it has data in it?

Comment: Have a data, if use "self.slug = self.title" works fine

Comment: Pretty sure it's a bug in mysql\connector\cursor.py, https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74675

Answer (score 1):

Try to use slugify function from [django.utils.text](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.text) instead of `django.template.defaultfilters`. Slugify from django.template.defaultfilters is template filter and it should use in template.

Comment: " from django.utils.text import slugify " Dont work :/

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had the same problem. This is how I fixed.

`slugify(self.title).__str__()`

Slugify returns a "SafeString" and it does not have any "strip()" function. So I get a "str" and it works.

Comment: this worked for me. Ugly ugly but nothing else seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This error means that `title` property of the created model doesn't have a value,
you need to make sure that your Page instance has the required attribute before you slugify its title.

the following code is a good workaround, but you still need to know why your model doesn't have a title when it is being saved.

```py
...
class Pages(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        if self.title and not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
     ...
```

An optimal solution for you is to use **[Django Autoslug](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)** library which will save you from all the hassle of setting a value for your slug field.

check it out:

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

class Pages(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=255)
    slug =  AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use django signals to solve this issue. Try adding the following code at the end of your models.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Pages)
def pre_save_pages(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.u_id:
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.title)
```